# Facing exception: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started site:stackoverflow.com

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-android

I'm executes automation with model of Keyword Framework on Mobile using selenium + TestNG + Appium - on Emulator device in my MAC OS (eclipse IDE),

using the following version via **.pom** file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.0</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

most of the action function well but I have Keyword that taking around 115 seconds to perform the action repeated 9 times every time on a different TestData (Products ID on e-commerce mobile app)

keyword performs the following actions:
1. clear search product text field.
2. enter the productID at search box.
3. select from list the found product.
4. when product details page presented copy (to ArrayList) the product details and print to log + report.
5. click + to add this product to cart

which means 5 actions on one keyword
so i guess it takes too much time each operation 
the question is

for 6-7 products it working well but the next products it causes this exception:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started site:stackoverflow.com
```

the question is where did I change the wait time when I left the MAC PC a long with no operation - changed also the MAC System Preferences energy saver to Never sleep when plug to electricity cable 
in order that emulator will not terminated for long time TestCase?

Manny thanks in advance to any one who save me this troubleshoot :-)

Answer (score 0):

**MAC System Preferences energy saver to Never sleep when plug to electricity cable in order that emulator will not terminated for long time TestCase** this has nothing with `Java` or `Appium`.
You get this exception due to driver timeout, you can set your own timeout by calling:
`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: I already did it when have tested on emulator and no matter what defined the time unites.seconds the time out always happens, when change to a real device I able to run automation scenario as much as I wanted and cat put even 30 seconds time unites without any problems, probably its an issue of emulator only. with a real device it's not happens